# AsyncTask after cancelling another one

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have the following problem:
My program must run two AsyncTask (one after the other, never simultaneously), one of them will carry out a socket communication through Bluetooth and the other will do it through WIFI.
So what I do is something like:

```
 if (bluetoothConnexion.closeBTConnexion()){
                            mainContext.startUDPTask();
                        }

public Boolean closeBTConnexion() {
    if (bluetoothServerTask != null){
        bluetoothServerTask.cancel(true);
        return bluetoothServerTask.isCancelled();
    }
    else
        return true;
}
```

So I execute the UDPtask just when the bluetooth one has been cancelled, but I am facing two problems:

1. Even though the bluetooth task is properly cancelled, the overridden method onCancelled() is never called
2. The second task is never executed, it runs on preExecute method but not doInBackground()

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute them serially you could try using a serial executor http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#SERIAL_EXECUTOR
it would be something like this:

```
 bluetoothServerTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR);
```

and then you can execute the other task with

```
udpTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR);
```

that way udpTask will only run when bluetoothServerTask have been finished.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried the serial executor but my problem keeps being that I cant get to the oncancelled() method of the task. I am think that it is because I am triying to cancel it from a BroadcastReceiver onReceive() event, is there a reason why I shouldnt cancel an AsyncTask from a BroadcastReceiver?